# Getting push to work with adhoc builds

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am following the tutorial on setting up iOS push here:

[Here - Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1)

It works for development builds, ie an app in Debug mode using Developer certificate. I can send messages to a single device using the provided simplepush.php script.

I can't get this to work with adhoc builds - which are built using the distribution certificate.

*What do I need to change in simplepush.php to make this work with adhoc builds?*

I changed **gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195** to **gateway.push.apple.com:2195** because I reckon the sandbox should be used for Development/debug builds, and adhoc and appstore builds should use gateway.push.apple.com:2195.

I get this response, but no messages are delivered to the device specified by the device token.

> Connected to APNS
>   Message successfully delivered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware of the `device token-ID`,

> which is different for the development && Production environment .

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {

       UIAlertView *alert= [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle: deviceToken message:Nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Thanks will try. I didn't know they are different and so am still using the same development device token.

Comment: 100% it is different . Even though the setUp is connected & sent, that mean the device is unknown . Change the Token-id. You will get it done

Comment: Thanks it worked. I'll accept your answer when the time limit allows.